# Detect anchor link clicked in CefSharp

Tags: winforms, cefsharp

I'm trying to trap "Control+Click" to open new windows/tabs in a CefSharp winforms client application.

The most obvious way was using `OnBeforeBrowse` on the `IRequestHandler`, so I did something like this (the actual function is more complicated, but never mind that):

```
public bool OnBeforeBrowse(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, bool isRedirect)
{      
  if (Control.ModifierKeys.HasFlag(Keys.Control) && request.TransitionType == TransitionType.LinkClicked)
  {
    MainForm.OpenChildWindow(new Uri(request.Url));
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

This definitely works for "normal" link clicks. But then when you click on an anchor link (that does some AJAX loading via javascript or whatever), two things happen:

1. If the link is the same as the currently loaded one or an anchor link in a different URL, it'll indeed call `OnBeforeBrowse` and it'll work correctly (opening a new window in my case).
2. If the link is an anchor link to the same URL but a different anchor, no `OnBeforeBrowse` is issued, so I can't control the loading via that way.

I tried using `OnBeforeResourceLoad`, but the `TransitionType` is `LinkClicked` for any resource it loads during the ajax call (and `GET`) and I just can't find anything different in the parameters for `OnBeforeResourceLoad` for the actually clicked link and the rest of the resources loaded.

Any ideas on how could I achieve that?

PS: not trying to make this an "XY problem", the actual problem (despite the title of the question) I'm trying to solve is, like I stated, open new tab/windows on ctrl+click (or middle click), so if there's any other way to do it, that's ok too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting a response for this issue from Alex Maitland (CefSharp's main contributor), seems a callback for this was added in the latest Cef (and CefSharp), which is now on latest CefSharp's master branch.

The answer was using `OnOpenUrlFromTab` on the `IRequestHandler` (it wasn't available on the version I was using) and checking `WindowOpenDisposition`.